# How to make an ontology public accessible?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

I have created an ontology in *Turtle syntax* and I want to start with S*PARQL querying*. I am using the Topbraid composer for that. At the moment the ontology is only stored locally on my laptop.
How can I publish it / host it somewhere?

Thank you

Comment: Try https://cloud.ontotext.com/

Comment: Putting an ontology online doesn't help. You have to load it in a triple store/SPARQL engine that provides access via e.g. HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload the ontology file to a web host through FTP, as you would do it with any other text file. This exposes the entire terminology (classes, properties, and individuals) of your ontology through the corresponding namespace URI, which has either a trailing slash (/) or a trailing hash mark (#). By using content negotiation on the web server, the ontology file can be served to semantic agents, and HTML5 content for humans. Ideally, you set up an ordinary website on the host, and depending on whether you use / or # between the domain name and the terms of your ontology, you create either dedicated pages for each ontology term (in the case of the first), or a section with the appropriate fragment identifier (in the case of the second), so that web browsers will render the description of each ontology term. Note that not everyone sets up a dedicated website for their ontologies, and many use symbolic URIs instead, which is not ideal, however, because only a proper documentation can ensure that the ontology terms will be implemented as expected.

If you want to publish your ontology so that it will be queryable through SPARQL, one of the options is to use OpenLink Virtuoso, Fuseki, or D2R. Alternatively, you can use a workaround, and employ a plugin, say the LH Tools plugin, if you use Wordpress for the site, to expose the RDF triples through a SPARQL endpoint. For really large ontologies, only the first option is recommended for performance reasons (RDF triples should be stored in triplestores).

To install an OpenLink Virtuoso SPARQL Endpoint, follow these steps:

1. Download Virtuoso Open Source from http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/
   dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSDownload or the commercial edition of
   Virtuoso from http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/.
2. For the commercial Windows Open Source Edition, run the installer; otherwise,
   create a build.
3. Verify the installation and the configuration of the environmental variables by
   running the virtuoso -? Command.
4. Start the Virtuoso server with virtuoso-start.sh.
5. Verify the connection to the Virtuoso Server, using isql localhost (if using the
   default DB settings), isql localhost:1112 (assuming demo database), or visit
   http://:[port]/conductor in your browser
6. Open the SPARQL endpoint at http://:
   [port]/sparql.
7. Run a test query such as SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 50.